# How to structure your templates when You have multiple designs but your CMS enables to upload ONLY 1 file with all styles and templates bundled in it?

Tags: html, css, templates, sass, gulp

I am creating templates for my e-commerce stores. I have multiple brands each with its own domain and specific design. Except those I will also create something like a master domain where there will be all products from each brand. The very base for my project is a customized CMS where I can upload all my templates bundled in only one .rar file. For template coding I use SASS, grunt/gulp + compass, JS, Freemarker and html.

I have never coded a project so extensive and dont know how to structure my templates so that in cases of future modification it will be easy to modify those templates. I am talking about problems like when You have 14 brands and want to add a specific action button only on 6 domains out of all 14 domains. Obviously, I dont want to go into each of those 6 brand's folders and EVERY TIME (6 times) add an HTML code and SASS styles for that button. On the other hand, I also dont want to compile and bundle SASS styles of all 14 brands into one CSS file because in that case I will be including this CSS file on each of my domain.

Have You ever had to deal with similar problem? - **You have multiple domains but your CMS enables You to upload ONLY 1 file with all styles and templates bundled in it.**

**Question is how to structure these templates** - *for example should I have my typography styles for every domain in one file named `_typography.scss` or should I have `_typography.scss` file for each of my brand?*

[image]

Comment: Why the heck did you downvote my question?

Answer (score 2):

You're using Gulp, so take advantage from your workflow.

1. Create 1 root SCSS file per brand:

```
assets/css/common/_variables.scss
assets/css/common/_typography.scss
assets/css/main.brand1.scss
assets/css/main.brand2.scss
assets/css/main.brand3.scss
```

2. Define default values for your variables in a file:

```
// assets/css/comon/_variables.scss
$font-main: Arial !default;
```

3. Override these values in brand-related root files:

```
// assets/css/main.brand1.scss
$font-main: 'Comic Sans';

@include 'common/variables';
@include 'common/typography';
```

4. Use these variables all other files:

```
// assets/css/common/_typography.scss
.h1 {
  font-family: $font-main;
}
```

5. Use Gulp to generate all your CSS files:

```
public/css/main.brand1.css
public/css/main.brand2.css
public/css/main.brand3.css
```